# No me funciona el if else en java swing jbutton

Tags: java-swing

bueno resulta que estoy haciendo un  programa  con java swing.
Se trata de cargar en un arraylist 266 preguntas   de un archivo.txt . En otro arraylist tengo las 266 respuesta que también lo cargo con otro archivo.txt .

Tengo un textfield  que el usuario debe introducir  la respuesta al hacer click sobre el botón un if else compara  el valor introducido  en el textfield  con la posición del arraylist la posición va avanzando con un contador que cada vez que se hace click sobre el botón el contador suma 1. Si el valor del textfield no es lo mismo que la posición del arraylist sale un mensaje "Error respuesta incorrecta"

El problema que tengo  es que   aunque  se introduzca un valor igual a la posición del arraylist siempre entra en el else es decir los valores nunca son iguales aunque  claramente si lo son incluso he puesto en el panel dos labels  para mostrar  lo introducido en el textfield con la posicion del arraylist en ese momento.

Lo curioso es que si cargo un Arraylist  manualmente como también se puede ver en el código que adjunto el botón con el if else si compara bien  los dos valores textfield y posicion arraylist.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class question_answer extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JButton btnAnswer;
    private JLabel lblNewLabelcuestion;
    private JLabel LabelTextF;
    private JLabel labelArraylistPos;
    private JLabel lblNewLabelTF;
    private JLabel lblNewLabelAL;
    static int count = 0;

    private JLabel lblNewLabel_1;
    private static JTextArea textArea;
    private JLabel lblNewLabel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    question_answer frame = new question_answer();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });

    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public question_answer() {
        File archive = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        //This works
        /*
         * ArrayList<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
         * question.add("What is your name?");
         * question.add("What is your surname?");
         * question.add("What is your age?");
         * ArrayList<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
         * answer.add("Pedro"); 
         * answer.add("Rodriguez");
         * answer.add("46");
         */

        ArrayList<String> answer1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            archive = new File("C:\\answer.txt");
            String line;
            fr = new FileReader(archive);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                answer1.add(line);
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        finally {
            try {
                if (fr != null) {
                    fr.close();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 567, 400);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        lblNewLabelcuestion = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabelcuestion.setBounds(60, 56, 360, 24);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabelcuestion);

        lblNewLabelTF = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabelTF.setBounds(60, 292, 56, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabelTF);

        LabelTextF = new JLabel("TextField");
        LabelTextF.setBounds(60, 263, 56, 16);
        contentPane.add(LabelTextF);

        lblNewLabelAL = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabelAL.setBounds(170, 292, 56, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabelAL);

        labelArraylistPos = new JLabel("Arraylist Position");
        labelArraylistPos.setBounds(170, 263, 110, 16);
        contentPane.add(labelArraylistPos);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(340, 139, 116, 22);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        lblNewLabelcuestion.setText(answer1.get(count));
        btnAnswer = new JButton("answer");

        lblNewLabelAL.setText(answer1.get(count));

        btnAnswer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                String line1;
                for (int j = 0; j < answer1.size(); j++) {
                    line1 = answer1.get(j);
                    textArea.append(line1);
                }

                lblNewLabelcuestion.setText(answer1.get(count));
                lblNewLabelAL.setText(answer1.get(count));
                lblNewLabelTF.setText(textField.getText());

                String c = answer1.get(count);
                String Tf = textField.getText();

                if (Tf.equals(c)) {
                    lblNewLabel_1.setText("Good");
                } else {
                    lblNewLabel_1.setText("Wrong");
                }
                count += 1;
            }
        });
        btnAnswer.setBounds(340, 198, 97, 25);
        contentPane.add(btnAnswer);

        lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("New label");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(45, 153, 256, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(345, 273, 181, 67);
        contentPane.add(textArea);

        lblNewLabel = new JLabel("achive.text  content");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(340, 244, 116, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
    }

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. 1) El `if` te funciona, igual tienes un problema en que la expresión no se evalúa como piensas. 2) Pon sólo el código relevante, leerme todo tu programa para adivinar ver a qué `if` te refieres es excesivo. Mira [ask] y [mcve]

Comment: Intenta usando la función `trim()` cuando obtienes los textos que va a comparar `String c = answer1.get(count).trim();` y `String Tf = textField.getText().trim();`, es posible que un espacio cause la diferencia.

Comment: Como @isaac pienso que el problema podría estar en algún espacio de más o de menos, o en el `count`.  Si lo del `trim` no funciona, prueba a empezar a contar desde `1`, en vez de hacerlo desde `0`.

Comment: perdon chico es que es la primera vez que tengo que pedir ayuda para un codigo que me tiene bloqueado una semana.

Comment: Isaac eres un crack  la solución fue solo String c = answer1.get(count).trim(); Gracias a  todos .